# The difference between 書店 and 本屋

Tags: words

What is the difference between:

書店 and 本屋

Are there any specific places where you can use one over the other? Or is it simply like the English Bookstore/Bookshop, and are perfectly interchangeable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`本屋` means bookstore. `書店` means bookstore or publishing company, latter of which would be normally called `出版社`. `書店` but not `本屋` can be used as affixal; there are `....書店` but no `...本屋` with this meaning. There are `[...本]屋` like `貸本屋`, but that has a different structure.

Comment: 書店 while technically meaning bookstore, often seems to be code for stores selling adult goods.